# Mutually Exclusive Bitbake Recipes/Tasks

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have several recipes who's `do_compile` task uses a lot of memory (lots of C++ templates). If I build the recipes at the same time, they exhaust the host machine of memory and the out-of-memory killer starts killing.

I've modified `BB_NUMBER_PARSE_THREADS`, `BB_NUMBER_THREADS`, `PARALLEL_MAKE`, and `PARALLEL_MAKEINST` numerous times, but it is not feasible to pick numbers for these variables that'll work well in all situations. For example, if I set `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` to `1` in order to get only one of these recipes to build at a time, I end up increasing the build time a lot when there are no changes (everything can be pulled from the cache). I don't feel like those are the right solution to my problem.

Is there any way to tell bitbake to only build one of these recipe's `do_compile` tasks at a  time, but let other recipe's tasks build normally?

Comment: Did you try disabling parallel make in those recipes? `PARALLEL_MAKE = ""`

Comment: That could potentially help a little, but unfortunately most of the template expansion is handled in a few source files; like a switch statement where dispatching is done to 60 different types, or a boost::msm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't quite the answer you're looking for but you could have something like:

```
do_compile[lockfiles] = "${WORKDIR}/mylock"
```

which would require the task to take and hold the lock to execute, then you can be sure only one would run at a time.

Comment: Actually I think that is a good solution. I didn't know about `lockfiles` on tasks. That should work well for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The lockfile would have to be in a location common to multiple recipes, so not ${WORKDIR}. Maybe "/tmp/mylock"?